# F# Output text file throwing error while input text file doesn't

Tags: c#, f#

So when I read my text file in using StreamReader, I'm able to create the gpa sequence below.

```ml
let pathtoinfile = @"c:\temp\Grades.txt";
let reader = new StreamReader(pathtoinfile)
let csv = reader.ReadToEnd()
let allInfo =
    csv.Split([|'\n'|])

let gpa =
    csv.Split([|'\n'|])
    |> Seq.map (fun line -> line.Split([|','|]))
    |> Seq.map (fun values -> float values.[5])
```

Now I convert the information from the file into an array and place into an output file.

```ml
let allArray = Seq.toArray allInfo;
let pathtooutfile = @"c:\temp\Grades2.txt";
File.WriteAllLines(pathtooutfile , allArray)
```

Now when I attempt to split the file I'm getting an IndexOutOfRangeException When I Write the array to a file does it change the format?  Not sure where I'm going wrong as both the files look the same when I compare them by inspection.

```ml
let reader2 = new StreamReader(pathtooutfile)
let csv2 = reader2.ReadToEnd()

let gpa2 =
    csv2.Split([|'\n'|])
    |> Seq.map (fun line -> line.Split([|','|]))
    |> Seq.map (fun values -> float values.[5])
```

Comment: If you are getting an error about an infox operator, then your code isn't even compiling.

Comment: I can open the newly created output file, just cannot split it.  It is compiling.

Comment: This error: error FS0010: Unexpected infix operator means that some of the code failed to compile.  YOu need to fix that first.

Comment: Okay, forget about that error, because it's irrelevant.  Look and the IndexOutOfRangeException as that's my problem.

Comment: `let gpa2 = csv.Split([|'\n'|])`, should that be referring to `csv2`?

Comment: Also, `let csv2 = reader.ReadToEnd()` should probably use `reader2` `reader` is already at the end.

Comment: Okay yeah thanks edited.  Still not my problem though as those are typo errors when transferring my code to here.  So anything else beside typos?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, going to answer my own question.  When you write to outfile there's a blank line that is placed at the bottom of the file.  The fix was to trim the csv string to remove all whitespace before splitting the string.  Hope this helps someone someday.

```
let csv = csv.Trim()
```